# How to set BackColor of Infragistic component using System.Reflection

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics, system.reflection

I have an application which uses Windows.Form together with Infragistics for GUI/UI. I wanted to seperate the allocation of properties like BackColor, ForeColor etc. from my main project to make it a bit more nicer to read and smaller. So I made a new project in VS(2017,Professional) where I set all properties using reflection because I wanted to avoid having a reference of my main project inside my GUI project.

I get the control Elements I want to change like this:

```
object controlsCollectionObject = currentObject.GetType().GetProperty("Controls").GetValue(currentObject);
ArrayList controlsInnerList = controlsCollectionObject.GetType().GetProperty("InnerList", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(controlsCollectionObject) as ArrayList;
```

This InnerList contains the control elements of that ControlCollection object.
I then iterate this list and look for two properties that I want to set:

```
Type listItemType = listItem.GetType();
if (wantedControls.Contains(listItem.GetType().Name))
{
   listItemName.Append(listItemType.GetProperty("Name").GetValue(listItem) as string);
   if (!controlElements.ContainsKey(listItemName.ToString()))
   {
      controlElements.Add(listItemName.ToString(), new Tuple<object, PropertyInfo>(listItem, listItemType.GetProperty("BackColor")));
   }
   if (listItemType.GetProperty("Appearance") != null)
   {
      appearanceObject = listItemType.GetProperty("Appearance").GetValue(listItem);
      listItemName.Append("_Appearance");
      controlElements.Add(listItemName.ToString(), new Tuple<object, PropertyInfo>(appearanceObject, appearanceObject.GetType().GetProperty("BackColor")));
   }
   if (!doNotPushInStack.Contains(listItem.GetType().Name))
   {
      objectsToIterate.Push(listItem);
   }
   listItemName.Clear();
}
```

Where `controlElements` is a `Dictionary<string, Tuple<object, PropertyInfo>>` and `wantedControls` is a string array that contains all control object types I want to find and change.

`objectsToIterate` is a `Stack<object>` that I used to avoid recursion and because I wanted to search certain controls aswell to check if they contain other controls I might want to change.

Afterwards I set the properties like this:

```
private static void SetControlProperties()
{
   Tuple<object,PropertyInfo> objectReferenceAndBackColor;
   DataRow dbPanels;

   for (int i = 0; i < panelsData.Length; i++)
   {
      dbPanels = panelsData[i];

      if(controlElements.TryGetValue(dbPanels["ButtonText"].ToString(), out objectReferenceAndBackColor))
      {
         objectReferenceAndBackColor.Item2.SetValue(objectReferenceAndBackColor.Item1, Color.FromName(dbPanels["BackColor1"].ToString()));
         Debug.WriteLine(objectReferenceAndBackColor.Item2.GetValue(objectReferenceAndBackColor.Item1).ToString() + " I am Object of: " + objectReferenceAndBackColor.Item1.ToString());
      }   
   }
}
```

`panelsData` is a `DataRow` that contains all my values I want to write into the properties. All the values are saved in a local SQL database.
The reason im checking for `["ButtonText"]` is because I temporarily wrote the datasets for the controls into my "Button" datatable

For most components like panels it works fine but some infragistics components, like UltraTextEditor, it doesn't work. It doesn't seem to register or take over the changes I set via SetValue() from reflections.

After it finishes when I check in my main project if the values have been set I see that certain components do not save these values:

`Color [Transparent] I am Object of: Infragistics.Win.UltraWinEditors.UltraTextEditor`

Instead it should look like this in the log:

`Color [255; 11; 110; 143] I am Object of: Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGrid`

The values I am trying to set are not readOnly. The `UltraTextEditor.UseAppStyling` is set to false aswell as the `UseOsThemes` property. I've also checked if my values are getting overwritten at some point but that is not the case. I used the same approach I've shown here inside my main project to see if it was a permission problem but that didn't work either.
I can set the backcolor of these components inside my main project by simply using `ultryTextEditorTest.BackColor = Color.Blue;` just fine but via reflection it does not write it into the property. I've checked the values from my database and the sql query in my code to see if I made a mistake but everything is correct so right now im not sure what problem is or at least, why it doesn't let me set the backcolor via reflection.

I know I could simply set the colors normally but at this point I am stubborn and want to know why it doesn't work or if it might be impossible to do it that way because infragistic forbids me to do so. That is, if infragistic is the problem or if I made a mistake in my code that I do not see.

I hope this isn't to much at once, if it is let me know and I'll try to break it down a bit more so it is easier to read and understand.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Did you see this thread of someone having a similar problem with the UltraTextEditor, though without reflection involved? https://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/f/ultimate-ui-for-windows-forms/110255/ultratexteditor-in-edit-mode-change-forecolor-of-the-font

Comment: @BartvanderDrift I did see this post but I think it does not solve the probem I have. I noticed when I focus the UltraTextEditor that it changes its color because of the TextBox that gets created but when I set the backcolor of the Appearance property of my UltraTextEditor it overrides the color of this TextBox and permanently shows the color it was assigned, focused or not. So I thought if I set the Appearance.BackColor via reflection that it should do the same but it isn't the case.

Comment: And did you try to set the UseOsThemes property?

Comment: Yes, I tried it both ways but the result is the same. The backcolor of the UltraTextEditor keeps its default color that is set inside the InitializeComponent() method from infragistics.